# Overload a lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, overloading, c++17, function-object

How to overload a simple local lambda function?

SSE of original problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void read()
{
    static std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    auto translate = [](int idx)
    {
        constexpr static int table[8]{ 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
        return table[idx];
    };

    auto translate = [](char c)
    {
        std::map<char, int> table{ {'a', 0}, {'b', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 3},
                                             {'e', 4}, {'f', 5}, {'g', 6}, {'h', 7} };
        return table[c];
    };

    int r = translate(static_cast<int>(line[0]));
    int c = translate(static_cast<char>(line[1]));
    std::cout << r << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    read();
    return 0;
}
```

The error messages

```
error: conflicting declaration 'auto translate'
note: previous declaration as 'read()::<lambda(int)> translate'
```

Please don't mind not checking user input, this is an SSE.

Comment: Lambdas are not functions, they are objects so overloading never applies to them. `translate` are just local variables that can not reuse the same name.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475576/c11-overloaded-lambda-with-variadic-template-and-variable-capture

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can not overload the lambda!

The lambdas are [anonymous functors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)(i.e. unnamed function objects), and not simple functions. Therefore, overloading those objects not possible.
What you basically trying to do is almost

```
struct <some_name>
{
    int operator()(int idx) const
    {
        return {}; // some int
    }
}translate; // >>> variable name

struct <some_name>
{
    int operator()(char idx) const
    {
        return {}; // some int
    }
}translate; // >>> variable name
```

Which is not possible, as the same variable name can not be reused in C++.

---

However, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we have [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) by which one can instantiate the only branch which is true at compile time.

Meaning the possible solutions are:

- A single [variabe template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) lambda. or
- A generic lambda and find the type of the parameter using [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype)
  for the `if constexpr` check.(credits *@NathanOliver*)

Using [variabe template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) you can do something like. **([See a live demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/nNmQuM))**

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

template<typename T>
constexpr auto translate = [](T idx) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
    {
        constexpr static int table[8]{ 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
        return table[idx];
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>)
    {
        std::map<char, int> table{ {'a', 0}, {'b', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 3}, {'e', 4}, {'f', 5}, {'g', 6}, {'h', 7} };
        return table[idx];
    }
};
```

and call it like

```
int r = translate<int>(line[0]);
int c = translate<char>(line[1]);
```

---

Using generic lambda(since [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)), the above will be: **([See a live demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/wFQe2F))**

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

constexpr auto translate = [](auto idx) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(idx), int>)
    {
        constexpr static int table[8]{ 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
        return table[idx];
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(idx), char>)
    {
        std::map<char, int> table{ {'a', 0}, {'b', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 3}, {'e', 4}, {'f', 5}, {'g', 6}, {'h', 7} };
        return table[idx];
    }
};
```

and call the lambda as you do now:

```
int r = translate(static_cast<int>(line[0]));
int c = translate(static_cast<char>(line[1]));
```

Comment: I find this amazing

Comment: First, your `else if` needs to be `else if constexpr`.  Secondly, why use a variable template?  You could just make the lambda generic and your checls would become `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(idx), int>)` and `else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(idx), char>)`

Comment: note that polymorphic lambda's are a thing if you don't mind using a wrapper class see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18432618/650492

Answer (score 12):

So the rules for overloading names **only apply to certain kinds of lookup of function names** (both free and methods).

Lambdas are not functions, they are objects with a function-call operator.  So overloading cannot occur between two different lambdas.

Now, you can get overload resolution to work with function objects, but only within the scope of a single object.  And then if there is more than one `operator()`, overload resoltion can pick between them.

A lambda, however, has no obvious way to have more than one `operator()`.  We can write a simple (in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) utility class to help us:

```
template<class...Fs>
struct overloaded : Fs... {
  using Fs::operator()...;
};
```

and a deduction guide:

```
template<class...Fs>
overloaded(Fs...) -> overloaded<Fs...>;
```

with these two, we can overload two lambdas:

```
static std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

auto translate_int = [](int idx){
    constexpr static int table[8] {7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
    return table[idx];
};

auto translate_char = [](char c) {
    std::map<char, int> table { {'a', 0}, {'b', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 3},
                                {'e', 4}, {'f', 5}, {'g', 6}, {'h', 7} };
    return table[c];
};
auto translate = overloaded{ translate_int, translate_char };

int r = translate(static_cast<int>(line[0]));
int c = translate(static_cast<char>(line[1]));
```

and done.

Writing `overloaded` is possible in both [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) but requires more work and is less elegant.  Once you are aware of the problem, finding a solution that matches what your particular compiler supports in the way of C++ features shouldn't be hard.

Comment: As I understand each "overloaded" lamda has it's own capture block, i.e. those lambdas don't share anything (and probably waste CPU time capturing same data over and over). Any chance C++ standard will have something to rectify that? Or only option is `variadic generic lamda` + `if constexpr` to separate calls?

Comment: @C.M. To ask a question on stack overflow, please press the [Ask Question] button to your top right, not the [Add Comment] button.  Thanks!

Comment: For C++11 version see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432260/lambda-functions-as-base-classes

Answer (score 7):

Lambdas are basically syntactic sugar for locally defined functors. As far as I know, they were never meant to be overloaded to be called with different parameters. Note that every lambda expression is of a different type, so even the immediate error aside, your code cannot work as intended.

You can however, define a functor with an overloaded `operator()`. This will be exactly what you'd get from lambdas if it was possible. You just dont get the terse syntax.

Something like:

```
void read()
{
    static std::string line;

    struct translator {
          int operator()(int idx) { /* ... */ }
          int operator()(char x)  { /* ... */ }
    };
    translator translate;


    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    int r = translate(static_cast<int>(line[0]));
    int c = translate(static_cast<char>(line[1]));

    std::cout << r << c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: wait a minute, you are calling lambda syntax nice??

Comment: @VTT it is nice that the syntax is terse. Compared to some more ancient things it isnt too bad

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `boost/hana/functional/overload`

```
#include <boost/hana/functional/overload.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void read()
{
    static std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);


    auto translate = boost::hana::overload(
      [](int idx) {
          constexpr static int table[8]{ 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 };
          return table[idx];
      },
      [](char c) {
        std::map<char, int> table{ {'a', 0}, {'b', 1}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 3},
                                   {'e', 4}, {'f', 5}, {'g', 6}, {'h', 7} };
        return table[c];
      }
      );
    
    int r = translate(static_cast<int>(line[0]));
    int c = translate(static_cast<char>(line[1]));
    std::cout << r << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    read();
    return 0;
}
```